# Sparkfun Pro Micro (ATMega32u4) as a controller of an USB Keyboard

Tags: arduino, keyboard, usb, avr, atmega

Im trying to use a Sparkfun Pro Micro as a controller for my keyboard. I can't achieve a normal keyboard's behaviour. This is my code:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

int firstButtonPin = 18, secondButtonPin = 19;
char firstButtonChar = 'z', secondButtonChar = 'x';
bool firstButtonPressed = false, secondButtonPressed = true;

void setup() {
  pinMode(firstButtonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(secondButtonPin, INPUT);

  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(firstButtonPin) == HIGH && firstButtonPressed == false) Keyboard.press(firstButtonChar), firstButtonPressed = true;
  else if(digitalRead(firstButtonPin) != HIGH && firstButtonPressed) Keyboard.release(firstButtonChar), firstButtonPressed = false;

  if(digitalRead(secondButtonPin) == HIGH && secondButtonPressed == false) Keyboard.press(secondButtonChar), secondButtonPressed = true;
  else if(digitalRead(secondButtonPin) != HIGH && secondButtonPressed) Keyboard.release(secondButtonChar), secondButtonPressed = false;
}
```

YT link: https://youtu.be/VfHNOtq4HHo.
As you can see, normal keyboard outputs a single key and after some time it spams. When i switch AVR, i get spam all the time (it looks like the keys are not being holded, just pressed and released in a very short period of time. How can I achieve a real keyboard's behaviour? I'd like to use it in games like Osu!. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem was button bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

u can use millis() to handle debouncing.

```
uint32_t time = millis(); //must be 32 bit or greater
uint8_t debounceTime = 50 //this is in milli seconds
void loop() {
    if (millis() - time > debounceTime) {

        //put your if-else-if code here (for keypress and release)
        time = millis();
    }
}
```

you have play around with the debounceTime. for most buttons 50 milli-seconds will do. but if you are using keyboard switches (like cherry mx, gateron etc) you can go as low as 5 milli-seconds